# Will I get Victorious Elise skin if I don't have the champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw that Elise will get the victorious skin after the end of S3. My question is whether I get the skin if I don't have Elise or not?

Comment: For all the other free skins you got the champ with the skin if you didn't have it already. I can't confirm for this one though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, along with any free skin there is always a free champion that comes with it.Very much similar to how server transfers may gift you a welcome skin and champion. e.g gladiator draven and pool party ziggs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's the same thing that if you subscribe on the League of Legends Youtube channel, you will get Unchained Alistar AND Alistar if you don't own him.